# using mockito to mock the class i'm testing

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Let's say i have a controller class called **UserController**, and withing it there are 2 methods: *getUserCount()* and *getLatestUser()*, and getUserCount calls getLatestUser.

```java
@Controller
class UserController{

public long getUserCount(){
#code
getLatestUser();
#code
}

public User getLatestUser(){}
}
```

i'm supposed to test each of these methods using Junit and Mockito, and thus i have something like this:

```java
class UserControllerTest{
@Autowired
UserController userController;

@Test
public void testing_get_user_count(){
User user = new User();
when(userController.getLastestUser()).thenReturn(user);
}
}
```

My issue is that i can't mock UserController because i've autowired it, so i can't use when().thenReturn() on getLatestUser.

Is there a way for me to mock it anyways?

Comment: Make it a `@Spy` instead

Comment: I would suggest following a guide on how to mock and test beans in spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@SpyBean` instead of `@Autowired`. It applies Mockito spy on a bean.

```java
class UserControllerTest {
  @SpyBean
  UserController userController;

  @Test
  public void testing_get_user_count(){
    User user = new User();
    when(userController.getLastestUser()).thenReturn(user);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah seems to be the best possible solution i could find, thanks :)